# Visual Studio 2010 Add Service Reference (WCF) "Proxy Auth" (407)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis, wcf-client

I'm having an issue adding a service reference to a sample client project using .NET 4.0, VS2010 and WCF.

The WCF service is deployed to IIS (6 at present) and I can browse the WSDL exposed by the MEX endpoint in IE at http://myServer.myDomain.net:8083/myService/actualService.svc?wsdl; but when I try to "Add Service Reference" and point it at the above address - I get the following error in VS:

Below is the error

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://myServer.myDomain.net:8083/myService/actualService.svc?wsdl'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

The service is configured to deny anonymous access, so I'm guessing I need VS to provide my credentials to the service before it will let me see the MEX/WSDL.

I've Googled around a bit, and found that people have been trying things like:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

But this doesn't seem to make a difference for me, I've also tried making sure that the URL for the web service is configured to be bypassed in IE settings.

Any ideas? Quite annoying when you want to consume a web service and get writing code.

Thanks
Pete

Comment: Just close the defaultProxy tag